# freebsd's newsyslog.conf daily logs rotate

Tags: freebsd, log-rotation

I'm trying to utilize `newsyslog.conf -- newsyslog(8) configuration file` to rotate my `apache`/`nginx`/`squid` log files:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD X 9.2-RELEASE-p17 FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p17 #0 r282430: Mon May  4 13:59:58 PDT 2015     root@X:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/R610  amd64
# tail -1 /etc/newsyslog.conf 
<include> /etc/newsyslog-local.conf
# cat /etc/newsyslog-local.conf 
/var/log/httpd-*.log    root:wheel  644 7   *   @T00    JC  /var/run/httpd.pid
/var/log/nginx-*.log    root:wheel  644 7   *   @T00    JC  /var/run/nginx.pid
/var/log/squid/*.log    squid:squid 640 7   *   @T00    JC  /var/run/squid/squid.pid
# newsyslog 
# echo $?
0
# ll /var/log/httpd-* /var/log/nginx-* /var/log/squid/*log*
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel   794179378 Jun 10 12:13 /var/log/httpd-access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel   236848603 Jun 10 12:09 /var/log/httpd-error.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel     3513917 Jun 10 12:09 /var/log/httpd-ssl_request.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  1789191504 Jun 10 12:13 /var/log/nginx-access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel   165855753 Jun 10 12:13 /var/log/nginx-error.log
-rw-r-----  1 squid  squid     5604675 Jun 10 12:01 /var/log/squid/access.log
-rw-r-----  1 squid  squid       12589 Jun 10 10:47 /var/log/squid/cache.log
#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Your configuration should be as follows:

```
/var/log/httpd-*.log    root:wheel  644 7   *   @T00    GBJC  /var/run/httpd.pid 1
/var/log/nginx-*.log    root:wheel  644 7   *   @T00    GBJC  /var/run/nginx.pid 1
/var/log/squid/*.log    squid:squid 640 7   *   @T00    GBJC  /var/run/squid/squid.pid 30
```

- The **G** flag indicates your log filename is a shell pattern.
- The **B** flag tells newsyslog to not put *Log rotated* text at the top of the new logfile.
- see **newsyslog.conf(5)** for other flag meanings.

If you want to use newsyslog for Squid, it needs to told not to do its own logrotate ([SquidLogs FAQ](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#I_want_to_use_another_tool_to_maintain_the_log_files.)):

```
# squid.conf
logfile_rotate 0
```

You can do a dry-run of your configuration with `newsyslog -nvF | less`.

My source for Squid config and dry-run command: ["Squid log rotation with newsyslog" (Jamesoff.net blog post and comments)](http://jamesoff.net/site/reference/squid-log-rotation-with-newsyslog/).

Answer (score 0):

Squid have its own log rotator:

```
#/etc/crontab
18 4 1 * * root /usr/local/sbin/squid -k rotate
```

config:

```
#/usr/local/etc/squid/squid.conf
logfile_rotate 10
```

Apache should be rotated carefully

```
#/etc/newsyslog.conf
/var/log/apache/vhosts/*.log 660 5 * $W0D0 CG 
/var/log/apache/tools/*.log  660 5 * $W0D0 CG 
/var/log/apache/*.log        660 5 * $W0D0 CG /var/run/httpd.pid 1
```

First you have to rotate all apache-related logs, then send a signal 1 (SIGHUP) to the master httpd process forcing logfile filedescriptors to be reopened.

Comment: Thank you for `squid -k rotate`, I added that to cron outside of newsyslog. re: apache i'm still unable to get that going, i added signal 1, but that did not help.

Comment: Aw! Newsyslog is launched by cron each minute and does nothing if noone timing pattern matched to current datetime. `@T00` means `each day midnight`. When you launch `newsyslog` manually at arbitrary time then  nothing would be happened - in general. Just wait until tomorrow.

Comment: Do I need to add signal 1 to `nginx` line as well?

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx, sorry.

Comment: well, tomorrow is today and neither `httpd` nor `nginx` log got rotated(